# How can we find out number of jobs active at a particular time while using schedule() in Python?

Tags: python, schedule

I want to create a scheduler which schedules multiple jobs each creating its thread after some point of time. So I want to prioritize the jobs, if two or more jobs are active at a time job x should be processed first. But for that I first should know if two or more jobs are active simultaneously. How can we check that?

I'm using `schedule()` to schedule jobs in Python 2.7.
here’s how my code snippet looks like:

```
import schedule
import time
def job1():
    print(x)
def job2():
    print(y)

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job1)
schedule.every(6).minutes.do(job2)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please, paste the code instead of pasting the image link. Besides, let us know what you have tried already.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvinience. Is the code not visible?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  If you can spell it out in more detail, someone may be able to help.  Perhaps you should get multithreading working at all before you try to build more complex job management.